# How to explicitly set msvc toolchain in conan profile

Tags: visual-studio-2022, conan, cl, conan-2

I'm testing my new library on windows and I want to make sure it also builds with MSVC. Now I say I want to test with multiple versions of msvc and I also have mingw and cygwin versions of gcc installed, how do I explicitly select the msvc compilers in a conan profile?

On Linux I would do something like this:

```
 [settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=11
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
os=Linux

[conf]
tools.build:compiler_executables={"cpp": "/usr/bin/g++-11", "c": "/usr/bin/gcc-11"}
```

But on Windows this seems to be a bit harder, since [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170) overview states that users should explicitly set the buildenv via a script to get all the right environment variables right. I'm not sure to what extent this is actually necessary, but I'm also not too familiar with msvc. I'm using a cmake buildsystem btw.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but for further details, specifics about some subsystem, things not working as expected, etc, much better to submit a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Answer (score 0):

If you have CMake and Visual Studio installed, all that is necessary is:

```
$ conan profile detect
```

Will detect the default profile using `msvc` compiler. This profile is good enough to be used to compile a CMake project. You can test it with:

```
$ conan new cmake_lib -d name=mypkg -d version=0.1
$ conan create .
```

Conan and CMake manage to setup everything that is needed to do the right build.
If you have different VS versions installed, just changing the version will do it too:

```
$ conan create . -s compiler.version=192
```

Where 193=VS 2022 (v143 toolset), 192=VS 2019 (v142 toolset), etc.

Compiling with Windows subsystems can require more configuration. Furthermore be aware that packages in ConanCenter are built in Windows with `msvc` only, that means they are not necessarily tested with MinGW or Cygwin, so some packages might fail to build/work in those subsystems.

It also depends which MinGW are you using, if the one in Msys2, or standalone. For building with them, the approach is:

- Define your own profile file with `os=Windows`, `compiler=gcc`, `compiler.version=<yourversion>`, `compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11`
- If you already have MinGW (including `mingw32-make`) and `gcc` in the path, then nothing else would be necessary. If they are not, you might want to add them to the `PATH+=(path)/path/to/mingw/bin` in the profile `[buildenv]` section.